# How can I open (or convert into .PGN) old Chessmaster .CMG files, without Chessmaster?

Tags: software, pgn, chessmaster

I have many old chess games saved from Chessmaster 7000, 8000, and maybe even 9000. They are all saved in the Chessmaster .CMG file format.

How can I access these games today?

I would like to either open them or convert them to .PGN format.

Comment: If I might ask, are you trying to resurrect Chessmaster?

Comment: Impossible without Chessmaster.

Comment: If I could learn the format, I could code this utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access them today, you either need to [reverse engineer the format](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/264) (hard) or [export them to PGN](http://www.chessdryad.com/education/henry/chessmaster/pg_01.htm) inside Chessmaster (moderate):

> HOW TO CONVERT CHESSMASTER GAME FILES (*.CMG) TO *.PGN FILES
>
> (*.CMG files or Chessmaster game files are typically for use with the
>   Chessmaster programs and may contain various enhancements, such as
>   annotations, illustrated voice analyses, etc. Cf. page 25 of the
>   Chessmaster 9000 user manual.)
>
> 1. Log in (on Chessmaster 9000) and go to Game Room.
> 2. Click on "File" in upper menu bar and then on "Load" in pull- down menu, to get "File Open" window.
> 3. By default, the "Look in" box will show a folder that is named the same as the name you log in with. Let's say it is "Loginame." If the
>      file you wish to convert is not in the list in the big box below, then
>      you will have to find it by scrolling to other folders. In front of
>      the file the little icon will contain the number 9000. (The icons for
>      *.PGN files contain the initials PGN.)
> 4. Click on the name of the *.CMG file that you wish to convert. The name will show in the "File name" box below. The "File of type" box
>      should mention Chessmaster files. Leave "Auto" in the last ("Open as")
>      box. Click the "Load" button and get the game on the board.
> 5. Click on "File" and then on "Save" in the pull-down menu.
> 6. "File Save" window comes up next. Check that the "Save in" folder is acceptable. (Your "Loginame" folder is OK, but you could even
>      scroll to save the file on the floppy in drive a:) In the "File name"
>      box below you can fill in a shorter (8-character) name of your choice,
>      rather than accepting the long name created by Windows. In the "Save
>      as type" box at the bottom,scroll and pick "PGN Game Files (*.PGN).
>      Click on the "Save" button. In the "Annotation Type" window that comes
>      up next, accept "None" by clicking "OK."
> 7. The *.CMG file has been stripped to the plain *.PGN format and saved in the folder that you have chosen. If you wish to add this file
>      to a database of your choice, see our earlier instructions under the
>      appropriate heading.

Obviously, if you don't have Chessmaster installed, you will need to do that.  Easiest way might be to [install a Windows VM](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/), then install a legacy copy of Chessmaster.

Comment: Clearly, this method will work, but you will have to repeat the steps to process each game individually. There is no method for bulk processing of CM format game databases.